# Como colocar string e variáveis juntas no Portugol?

Tags: algoritmo, portugol

Olá, estou aprendendo Portugol para fins acadêmicos e estou tendo problemas num código que estou fazendo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que quando eu executo, ele roda até chegar na hora de dar a média. Aí ele fala que não encontrou a variável aluno. Beleza eu tirei o aluno e fiz assim

```
escreval ("sua média é " media)
```

Apareceu que a sintaxe está incorreta. Mas não achei na internet como eu faço pra juntar uma string e a variável no "escreval".

Answer (score 2):

Use **vírgulas** para interpolar strings e variáveis:

```
escreval(aluno, ", sua média é ", media)
```

Comment: valeu! Eu não sabia qual a sintaxe correta porque tava usando o ponto pra concatenar igual eu faço em php '-' mas agora resolvi!